# Problem converting NSDATA

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdata

I'm a young iPhone developer and I'm trying to write an iPhone app that syncs data from a server side app on my mac, basically text data.

I'm having trouble reading data on the iPhone side with the following:

`

```
(void)connectionReceived:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSFileHandle *incomingConnection = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationFileHandleItem];

    [[aNotification object] acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify];

    NSData *receivedData = [incomingConnection availableData];

 NSString *theString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

`

I need to print out theString to a text label on the iPhone, but what I get is the exact "hex code translation" of the text entered on the server side app and I don't seem to be able to convert it to char.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer - but there are a few things to look at or try:

1. Did you try converting into something other than UTF8? (Unicode? ASCII?)
2. In the hex output it gives you - I assume it is giving a UTF8 representation - i.e. one 8-bit (two hex nibble) code for each character in your string. Is this the case? Are the hex codes "correct" for a UTF-8 or ASCII representation of your string?
3. Are there any "bad" codes in the result?

I am wondering if this is happening because there are characters (maybe even invisable ones - control characters - nulls, whatever) in your string which are making it so iOS can't do a "normal" UTF8 conversion...